# Scanner Object skips to second Scanner Object

Tags: java

So I am doing a project to put values into a scanner object and retrieve them. I am having a problem with the first input. The user is asked to input an ID and then should be asked for the last name.The problem is that when I run the first question it displays it but skips the first scanner input and jumps to the second question and input returns to normal. So what is happening here? And how do I solve this?

```
//Prompt user for each value
                System.out.println("Enter employee Id number:");
                String inputId = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter employees last name:");
                String inputLastName = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter employees first name:");
                String inputFirstName = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter employees salary:");
                String inputSalary = scanner.nextLine();        
                Double inSalary = Double.parseDouble(inputSalary);
```

Comment: For the first method, use `scanner.next()` and see what happens. I think this might be the problem.

Comment: befor or after the first input?

Comment: Change the first input. I think what's happening is that it is reading a blank line before you even type anything. So change it to `String inputId = scanner.next()`

Comment: OK that works but it skipped the second and went to the third so I did the same to all  as I did with the first and now it seems to work. However I wonder why this is happening and if there will be further issues by using scanner.next();

Comment: No, it should work fine. What `nextLine()` does, is it takes every character/digit from that line. But with `next()` it just takes the first word. Shouldn't really make a difference unless  you have a word that has a space in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have same problem with you, and i change .nextLine() with .next()
and that is how i fix my problem

try this

```
System.out.println("Enter employee Id number:");
           String inputId = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter employees last name:");
            String inputLastName = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter employees first name:");
            String inputFirstName = scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Enter employees salary:");
            String inputSalary = scanner.next();        
            Double inSalary = Double.parseDouble(inputSalary);
```